# Processing examples with different sequence lengths using Keras LSTM layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I need to train a stack of LSTM layers using examples with different sequence lengths. If we use the Keras sequential model, we may implement the code as follows.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, 5)))
model.add(LSTM(8, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))

def train_generator():
    while True:
        sequence_length = np.random.randint(10, 100)
        x_train = np.random.random((1000, sequence_length, 5))
        # y_train will depend on past 5 timesteps of x
        y_train = x_train[:, :, 0]
        for i in range(1, 5):
            y_train[:, i:] += x_train[:, :-i, i]
        y_train = to_categorical(y_train > 2.5)
        yield x_train, y_train

model1.fit_generator(train_generator(), steps_per_epoch=2, epochs=2, verbose=1)
```

The above is based on what I searched in another question:
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26366/training-an-rnn-with-examples-of-different-lengths-in-keras.
The above code works fine, and the above model can be trained using examples with different lengths.

However, in my case, I **should** subclass tf.keras.Model rather than using the sequential model.

```
class LSTMModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LSTMModel, self).__init__()

        self._lstm_0 = LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, 5)) 
        self._lstm_1 = LSTM(8, return_sequences=True)
        self._dense = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')

    def call(self, inputs, training=False):
        output = self._lstm_0(inputs)
        output = self._lstm_1(output)
        output = self._dense(output)

        return output
```

My expectation is that this second code should be equivalent to the first one. However, it crashes with the following error message.

```
BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Invalid argument: Operation expected a list with 33 elements but got a list with 27 elements
```

Could anyone tell me the reason and give some advice?

Comment: Why is everyone going for subclassing model? This sounds so Pytorch-ish...

Comment: I imagine your generator is not working correctly... maybe you should print the shapes of `x_train` and `y_train` before `yield` to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Everything executed with Tensorflow 1.14**

I run the following code using to include all the utils:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

def train_generator():
    while True:
        sequence_length = np.random.randint(10, 100)
        x_train = np.random.random((1000, sequence_length, 5))
        # y_train will depend on past 5 timesteps of x
        y_train = x_train[:, :, 0]
        for i in range(1, 5):
            y_train[:, i:] += x_train[:, :-i, i]
        y_train = to_categorical(y_train > 2.5)
        yield x_train, y_train
```

Then the first model is:

```
model_1 = Sequential()
model_1.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, 5)))
model_1.add(LSTM(8, return_sequences=True))
model_1.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
model_1.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse")
model_1.fit_generator(train_generator(), steps_per_epoch=2, epochs=2, verbose=1)
```

And the second model is:

```
class LSTMModel(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LSTMModel, self).__init__()

        self._lstm_0 = LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, 5)) 
        self._lstm_1 = LSTM(8, return_sequences=True)
        self._dense = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')

    def call(self, inputs, training=False):
        output = self._lstm_0(inputs)
        output = self._lstm_1(output)
        output = self._dense(output)

        return output

model_2 = LSTMModel()
model_2.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse")
model_2.fit_generator(train_generator(), steps_per_epoch=2, epochs=2, verbose=1)
```

The results were equivalent. If it still fails on your end, include more information in the question such as the TF version you you are running.

---

As per the opened [Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31816), this is a bug and has been solved in `tf-nightly-gpu-2.0-preview`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The second model you posted still fails for me with the following error. I'm currently using tensorflow 2.0-beta1.  
                                   
 tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  [_Derived_]  Operation expected a list with 27 elements but got a list with 82 elements.
  [[{{node gradients/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorListFromTensor_grad/TensorListStack}}]]
  [[Adam/gradients/lstm_model/lstm_1/StatefulPartitionedCall_grad/StatefulPartitionedCall]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_2970] .

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The error is in your data generator. Can you update the question with further explanation about what are you trying to achieve with your data generator?

Comment: Thank you, just for curiosity, I tried tensorflow 1.14. In this case, it works fine without any errors. So, I think this error only occurs with tensorflow 2.0-beta1? By the way, I think the error means that the layer expects to have the same number of  elements (sequence length) as the first data feeding.

Comment: Yes, the error occurs with TF 2.0, and you are right about the error origin. However, it is weird. I will dig into it a bit more and post an update.

Comment: I opened a Github issue (linked in the answer) for the `TF 2.0` use-case. Will update once there is a reply.

Comment: Hey @chanwcom, please see the update in the Github issue.